# libgdx box2d occassional crash on createBody

Tags: libgdx, box2d, jvm-crash

My game crashes with this message:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=13948, tid=12700
# [...]
# 
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
```

From log file:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniCreateBody(JIFFFFFFFFZZZZZF)J+0
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.createBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;+80
j  de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Food.<init>(Lde/tennoxlab/cellolution/CellWorld;FFZZ)V+115
j  de.tennoxlab.cellolution.CellWorld.generateFood(IFFFFZ)V+54
J 89 C2 de.tennoxlab.cellolution.CellWorld.update()V (159 bytes) @ 0x00000000024623b4 [0x0000000002461c60+0x754]
j  de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Cellolution.render()V+40
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+698
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Full log: http://pastebin.com/QjY3msYS

From all the other posts with similar crashes it is probably some world modification when it shouldn't happen.
The crash occurs during the creation of new Food objects:

```
// generateFood() - called during World.update
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    float x = minX + (float) Math.random() * (maxX - minX);
    float y = minY + (float) Math.random() * (maxY - minY);
    Gdx.app.debug("World", "Generating food piece "+i);
    this.foods.add(new Food(this, x, y, animateGrowth, this.renderable));
}
```

in the Food constructor:

```
// in Food(...) constructor
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef(); //TODO: set to sleep on init?
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(x, y);
bodyDef.linearDamping = 0.5f;
bodyDef.angularDamping = 1f;
Gdx.app.debug("Food", "Init body with " + bodyDef + " at " + x + "," + y);
foodBody = world.box2dWorld.createBody(bodyDef);  // <== HERE IS WHERE THE CRASH HAPPENS
CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
shape.setRadius(getSizeFromEnergy());
fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.2f;
fixture = foodBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
fixture.setUserData(this);
shape.dispose();
```

But it only happens occassionally, sometimes after minutes of gameplay (when the generateFood code was executed successfully hundreds of times). So I thought, the crash must have something to do with what happens with the world BEFORE the Food generation. So I started enabling and disabling code, until I found out, that **the crash only happens, when after the destruction of box2d bodies of my Cell objects**:

```
public void update() { // Cell.update - called during World.update
    if (this.energy <= 0) {
        world.cells.remove(this);
        Vector2 pos = cellBody.getPosition();
        Gdx.app.debug("Cell", "Destroying " + cellBody+" at "+pos.x+","+pos.y);
        world.box2dWorld.destroyBody(cellBody); // -> Without this line, the crashes don't happen!
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's the log:

```
World: Generating food piece 99
Food: Init body with com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef@72aff016 at -28.201607,-56.101532
World: Removing cell: de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Cell@7cbb6f2c
Cell: Destroying com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body@757ff1ad at -51.92446,-56.464954
World: Removing cell: de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Cell@7cbb6f2c
Cell: Destroying com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body@757ff1ad at -51.92446,-56.464954
World: Generating 100 new food pieces
World: Generating food piece 0
Food: Init body with com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef@3828ef8f at 14.653984,96.249084
[...]
World: Generating food piece 21
Food: Init body with com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef@2b91d887 at -15.35305,13.934067
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=9792, tid=13288
#
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. It was a nasty little bug like in probably all the other problems like that.

As you can see in the log file, the same Cell is deleted **twice**:

```
World: Removing cell: de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Cell@7cbb6f2c
Cell: Destroying com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body@757ff1ad at -51.92446,-56.464954
World: Removing cell: de.tennoxlab.cellolution.Cell@7cbb6f2c
Cell: Destroying com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body@757ff1ad at -51.92446,-56.464954
```

When I realised that I quickly found the issue: I have been adding the Player cell to the list twice, thus updating it twice, destroying it twice - which box2d obviously didn't like.

**As these 'solutions' to crashes like these don't really help if you got this crash yourself (because your bug will be something else), I can only suggest trying to figure out the problem by rigorious debugging. (I added tons of debug log lines everywhere and examined the output - for many hours...) Because mistakes like these happen. For some more frequently, for some less frequently, but they happen.**

Something else I want to add: box2d crash messages are really unhelpful. It is really hard to find out, what **really* caused the crash. That sucks. I wish there would be more debugging information, more safety checks and stuff like that in the library itself (or libgdx, maybe).

I'm really looking forward to more of those (seemingly) unsolvable bugs/crashes during the ongoing developement of the game :Z

Comment: Thanks from someone who had to deal with this issue in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You already solved your problem but if someone stubles upon this thread: In my case the issue was, that a Box2D world was disposed twice.